# Eclipse UI freezes on running TestNG tests at 57%

Tags: eclipse, testng, socket-timeout-exception

I am noticing that the Eclipse UI gets stuck at 57% when I try to run the TestNG test cases. I juts have the TestNG setup in the Library (Build path) and no Jars being present. How do I fix this? I am sitting on this for hours now.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.BaseMessageSender.initReceiver(BaseMessageSender.java:128)
    at org.testng.eclipse.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.startTestRunListening(TestRunnerViewPart.java:362)
    at org.testng.eclipse.TestNGPlugin.connectTestRunner(TestNGPlugin.java:213)
    at org.testng.eclipse.TestNGPlugin$2.run(TestNGPlugin.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134) at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [known issue](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/55). I experienced it also in the past. Unfortunately I don't know what fixed it for me. All I know it doesn't happen for me in STS versions based on Eclipse 4. But I also created workspace from scratch various times since.

Answer (score 0):

Kill Eclipse, restart it, clear all your breakpoints, then reset the ones you want. This works for me in Eclipse Luna v4.4.1.

See https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/55

Also double check the TestNG libraries in your classpath. I have a Maven project where some old ones got resolved and put in the classpath. I moved the TestNG dependency higher up in the dependencies section of the pom.xml and that fixed it when removing the breakpoints didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a new workspace and import your project.** Your old workspace is broke.